# Trouble compiling 'hello world' kernel module in 4.3.0-sabayon linux

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, gentoo

I am trying to compile a simple kernel module.  The Makefile is:

```
obj-m += hello-l.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The errors are:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-4.3.0-sabayon'
Makefile:340: scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory
Makefile:605: arch/x86/Makefile: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./scripts/gcc-goto.sh: No such file or directory
Makefile:778: scripts/Makefile.kasan: No such file or directory
Makefile:779: scripts/Makefile.extrawarn: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'scripts/Makefile.extrawarn'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-4.3.0-sabayon'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been able to compile this code on an Ubuntu machine.  Why would the sabayon machine be missing the files necessary to compile even the simplest code?

Answer (score 0):

What does the following command show:

```
ls -al /usr/src/linux-4.3.0-sabayon
```

Could it be that the kernel devel headers are not installed on the Sabayon Linux machine? In Fedora, the rpm is called kernel-devel. I do not have any idea how a similar package is called in Ubuntu, which is a derivative of Gentoo.

Comment: The output of ls -al /usr/src/linux-4.3.0-sabayon is:  

total 5156
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan  5  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    4096 Dec 30 12:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177673 Dec 16  2015 .config
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Jan  5  2016 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   54503 Dec 16  2015 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1262265 Dec 16  2015 Module.symvers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3761878 Dec 16  2015 System.map

I searched (equo search kernel header) and the results say that I have headers installed.  Not sure where to look for them however.

Comment: Your two queries should be posted as a comment, and not as an answer.  BTW Ubuntu is not *"a dervative [sic] of Gentoo"*; it's a well-known Debian-based distro.

Comment: It was a typo, apologies. I meant that sabayon is a derivative of gentoo, and not that Ubuntu is a derivative of gentoo.                                                                                         Rami Rosen